# Translate "socket.io" calls into plain old data

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I'm writing an application that needs to send data to a socket and receive data from the socket.

I know how to do this; I've done it several times before it other apps.

Unfortunately, the only documentation I have for the server I need to communicate with in the current project is in the form of a JavaScript file that uses some library called "Socket.IO". I am not familiar with this library (or JavaScript for that matter).

The JavaScript code contains statements such as "io.connect" with a parameter that looks like a web site URL, as well as multiple "emit" statements that have at least two parameters each. I need to know exactly what these statements are doing in terms of: what host and port is it connecting to? What bytes is it sending to the socket?

Where can I find this information?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Do you have access to the node server or server where this code is being run?

Comment: Not directly, but I have access to someone who does.

Comment: Socket.io is documented, and you can find that on the Web, but you should reject this assignment, or insist on proper protocol documentation if it's an in-house server.You should not have to reverse-engineer things in this day and age. There is no excuse for this.

Comment: Don't confuse socket.io with a standard TCP socket.  Socket.io gets the "socket" part of it's name from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket.

Comment: I get it now. Websocket is just the name of a TCP-based protocol that happens to contain the word "socket", it is not an actual socket. As is so often the case, web developers looking to shoehorn functional code into the limits of web browsers have come up with something that they now expect everyone to use, whether or not the application is web-based. As a non-web developer, I kind of resent that. In any case, I've found a Websocket library for the platform I'm using, so I'm no longer concerned about reverse-engineering the protocol.